# How to create scheduled task automatically?

Tags: apex, trigger, process-builder

In my Contact record I'm using a custom field of type date. I need to be able to create a new task record 30 days prior to the custom date field value. I tried using the standard process builder with following conditions:
[image]

Where
[Contact].Date__c `Is null` Boolean `False`
AND
[Contact].Date__c `Is changed` Boolean `True`

Upon create of new Contact records via the process builder `ISCHANGED()` cannot be used because the value in the custom date field is `NEW` but not `CHANGED` and it will not enable scheduled action option. In other words the task I need to create 30 days prior to the custom date field will not work. To mention that I need this process to work on update as well.

Because it is obvious I cannot achieve what I need by using the standard Salesforce process builder I decided to use apex.

However the issue I face with apex here is the limit of apex scheduled jobs it is possible to submit up to max 100 batch jobs.

Please advise what else I can try to be able to create Task record 30 days prior to custom date field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should still be able to use Process Builder.

Remove the `Is changed` condition altogether and try marking the checkbox true on the Advanced -> "Do you want to execute the actions only when specified changes are made to the record?" as shown below:

[image]

This will effectively run itself on both insert and updates to the record's custom date field.

Comment: I tried what you suggested. There is no trace of the process in the log file. How can I find all time-dependent actions placed in the queue - scheduled for execution?

Comment: @sfdcadmdev Try Setup -> Process Automation -> Flows.  Look at the bottom section called "Paused or Waiting Interviews".  I believe this is where Process Builder items show up when they're scheduled for execution.